# Macbook Air Charging Habit

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging

I'm using Macbook air 2020 M1, use it for my main driver, and I usually work quite a lot both in workplace and home.

Since MBA 2020 has amazing battery life, usually I don't bring my charger to workplace but charge all the time when I work at home. Thus, battery charging cycle on that habit is 100% on starting day and down to around 20% at the end of day. When I work at home I have it fully charged and keep it plugged in to power until morning (when I ready to go to my workplace).

**My question is**, is that charging habit okay for my battery healthy? Or is there any better charging habit recommendation?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the battery in a very good manner. I would let it optimize charging and carry on. Not regularly using the battery is the hardest thing you can do, but Apple has made good strides to prevent that from prematurely aging the chemistry.

Run these M1 macs hard is my advice.

If you think you’ll use this for 5 years, I might get AppleCare (ongoing) so you can have them swap the battery around year 4. Price out a paid out of warranty swap and decide if you lose if you only have that one service in the first 5 years. My MacBook one went 6 years before I paid for a battery swap.